# Why my jQuery switch not working on second page of table in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have that button which change db column status value, but it works only for the first 10 row of the table. On the 2nd page it does not work. Help me, I'm new.
Here it is button code:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="{{ $customer->id }}" name="status" class="js-switch" {{ $customer->status == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
            <td>
```

it is jquery

```
let elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    let switchery = new Switchery(html,  { size: 'small' });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-switch').change(function () {
        let status = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
        let userId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ route('users.update.status') }}',
            data: {'status': status, 'user_id': userId},
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/one/#one-events-data-handler) method, this way it will add event listener on newly added items too:

```
let elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    let switchery = new Switchery(html,  { size: 'small' });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-switch').on('change',function () {
        let status = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
        let userId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ route('users.update.status') }}',
            data: {'status': status, 'user_id': userId},
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx for ur contribution but i tested this but it is not worked